# Selenium error intercepted-not clickable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping

Intente varias soluciones que encontré acá pero ninguna me funciono sigo obteniendo este código de error :

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message:
>   element click intercepted: Element ... is
>   not clickable at point (509, 20). Other element would receive the
>   click:

```py
def Carre():
    url="https://www.carrefour.com.ar/informatica/impresoras-y-cartuchos.html"
    chrome_path=r"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe"
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    driver.get(url)
    lenOfPage= driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    match=False
    while(match==False):
        lastcount=lenOfPage
        time.sleep(2)
        lenOfPage=driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
        if lastcount==lenOfPage:
            match=True

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="top"]/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/a')))
    Create = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="top"]/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/a')
    Create.click()
```

agregue la linea para ejecutar el click con JS y ahora me cierra el navegador

```
def Carre():
    url="https://www.carrefour.com.ar/informatica/impresoras-y-cartuchos.html"
    chrome_path=r"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe"
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    driver.get(url)
    lenOfPage= driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    match=False
    while(match==False):
        lastcount=lenOfPage
        time.sleep(2)
        lenOfPage=driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
        if lastcount==lenOfPage:
            match=True

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="top"]/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/a')))
    Create = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="top"]/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/a')
    #Create.click()
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Create)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que el navegador hace *scroll* hasta el botón, pero al intentar
hacer *click* sobre él, no puede porque tiene a la barra con el buscador encima.

Para solucionarlo podes hacer *click* en el botón usando Javascript:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Create)
```

---

Para evitar que se cierre al finalizar el script de Python tenes que
pasarle al `driver` la opción `detach` de esta forma:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Gracias! Estoy probandolo , y ahora no me tira error , pero me cierra la ventana de navegador , me voy a poner a investigar porque es y si no encuentro el porque aviso

Comment: no hay .caso , actualice chrome y tambien el webdriver , pero cuando ejecuto el script me cierra automaticamente el navegador (edite la pregunta original , cambiando con el execute script desde js  por si lo meti en cualquier lado , sinceramente nunca utilice JS quizas estoy haciendo cualquiera...

Comment: @MatiasOrdoñez está bien donde lo pusiste, es normal que se cierre. Ahora edito mi respuesta para mostrarte como evitarlo